# How to change minLargeMessageSize in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a clustered environment of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.5. One of the consumers cannot use the Artemis JMS client jars so it is using client libs for ActiveMQ 5.11 (Java 1.7) to read the messages. This works fine for small messages. For some reason the consumer (3rd party product) cannot read large messages if they are chunked (and streamed). We have had success with large messages in our previous environment using HornetQ.

So my thought is to find a workaround for this by changing some parameters. But I don't have any success. There is a limit of 100 KiB. How can I change this limit to 5 MB? Can I set the MessageType allowed on a certain Queue? Only TextMessage/ByteMessage?

I don't want Artemis to treat messages below 5 MB as large. TextMessage, ByteMessage should be OK. Not StreamMessage as it does not seem to be supported.

I have seen settings like: JMS Bridge: min-large-message-size   Limit before message is considered large. default 100KB Cluster Connection Type:

min-large-message-size Messages larger than this are considered large-messages, default=100KB

Will I change it on the Client side like:
From the Manual (Where do I do this and how? It is a Cluster as well)

> **Using JMS**
>
> If JNDI is used to instantiate and look up the connection factory, the minimum large message size is configured in the JNDI context environment, e.g. `jndi.properties`. Here's a simple example using the "ConnectionFactory" connection factory which is available in the context by default:
>
> ```
> java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
> connectionFactory.myConnectionFactory=tcp://localhost:61616?minLargeMessageSize=250000
> ```
>
> If the connection factory is being instantiated directly, the minimum large message size is specified by `ActiveMQConnectionFactory.setMinLargeMessageSize`.
>
> **Configuring the Core Client**
>
> Any message larger than a certain size is considered a large message. Large messages will be split up and sent in fragments. This is determined by the URL parameter `minLargeMessageSize`.
>
> ---
>
> **Note**
>
> Apache ActiveMQ Artemis messages are encoded using 2 bytes per character so if the message data is filled with ASCII characters (which are 1 byte) the size of the resulting Apache ActiveMQ Artemis message would roughly double. This is important when calculating the size of a "large" message as it may appear to be less than the `minLargeMessageSize` before it is sent, but it then turns into a "large" message once it is encoded.
>
> The default value is 100KiB.
>
> ---
>
> [Configuring the transport directly from the client side](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-the-transport-directly-from-the-client) will provide more information on how to instantiate the core session factory or JMS connection factory.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: I am using Artemis 2.5.

Comment: Is the 3rd party product which is having trouble with large messages the one that is using ActiveMQ 5.x (i.e. OpenWire) libraries to consume?

Comment: Did you ever find out a way to set this? We are sending messages over tcp via openwire and no setting seems to work